# Add GRUB boot entry for Windows 10 installer iso

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm trying to install Windows 10 to a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04.
Secure boot is enable and I CAN'T DISABLE IT.

I want to try to add a menu entry in the GRUB boot menu for the Windows 10 installer. Selecting to boot it from GRUB shall start the Windows 10 installation.

My computer has two hard disks, both of them with a GPT partition table. Ubuntu and GRUB is installed on one of them, the other disk is for Windows.

The Windows 10 installer iso image is on a USB stick, but I could also save it on the hard disk.

How can I add a GRUB boot entry for the Windows 10 installer?

Comment: I don't understand your question and not because of language... If Ubuntu is already installed with secure boot on, why are you trying to disable it to install Windows 10? And if you already managed to boot the installer what is the problem now? Anyway, Windows installation is off-topic here.

Comment: I want dual boot with ubuntu and windows, but with secure boot enable I can't install windows 10

Comment: Again, off-topic.

Comment: Have you tried communicating with the manufacturer of your Laptop of how to disable Secure boot, or what is the process for installing Windows 10?  Running the Windows 10 doesn't have anything to do with what is already on the Hard Drive.  A computer should come with an option to boot to an install disk.  If it's incapable of running Windows 10 Install, the computer maybe defective.  Finally... what is the make and model number of your Laptop?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: @CelticWarrior The OP is running Ubuntu.  Properly adding dual boot to Ubuntu may not be too far from the Ubuntu topic.  He wants to include the Other OS in his Grub/Ubuntu boot menu.  Some definition that he can simply just boot to the Windows install, then update his Grub is an important component that we can provide.

Comment: Yes, but we're not there yet and the question is about secure boot and running the Windows installer from Grub with the ISO, apparently successful because *When I select Install windows 10, the install process begin*, so whatever comes next is purely Windows installation. What comes after installing Windows and setting up a proper dual is arguably relevant here. The actual starting point of this question is not.

Comment: @CelticWarrior By default I have a certain tolerance for the user's lack of technical skills to explain their problem perfect.  The tolerance becomes even higher when the user makes it clear in their question that their native language isn't English.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't add a USB install media or DVD install media to Grub.**  When you install grub or run Grub update it will automatically add the detected Installed OSes to the grub menu.  Windows isn't installed on the USB Windows Install ISO.

You would have to install Windows 10 to your computer.  If you'll having problems setting the BIOS to run the Windows 10 disk installer, you'll have to **consult with your computer's manufacturer for how to Boot to the Windows I install Disk.**
When you install Windows 10, it will likely cause the Grub not to function correctly, and the computer will boot directly into Windows 10, without recognizing that Ubuntu is installed.

Your next step would be to Update Grub.

**Repair Grub after Installing Windows**

You can update grub by booting into the Ubuntu live session.  Bring up a terminal screen with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  Then run these steps.

- Mount the partition with the Ubuntu installation:

```bash
$ sudo mount /dev/sdaX
```

- Link the system needed directorys for the grup install/update (the `$` symbol represents the command prompt where you will type the command):

```bash
$ for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
```

- Change make the Installed Ubuntu your effective root

```bash
$ sudo chroot /mnt
```

- Install and update grub (Replace 'X' with the drive letter of your boot drive... most likely `/dev/sda`).  The `#` represent the command prompt you see in the terminal commandline.

```
# grub-install /dev/sdX
# update-grub
# exit
$ sudo for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo umount "/mnt/$i"; done
$ sudo umount /mnt
```

- Reboot the computer

Now check and ensure your BIOS is set to Ubuntu and you'll have both Ubuntu and Windows 10 as your boot options.